# QR Code playing video on iPhone but not playing the sound

Tags: iphone, video, mobile, mp4, qr-code

I have a QR code set up to play a video.

It is pointing to an MP4 file, which works fine with sound when navigating to this using safari on the iPhone.

However, when I use the QR code to view the video on the iPhone the sound isn't working.

Here are the links for reference.

Video file: http://www.remarkablegroup.co.uk/temp/prokill.mp4

QR:[image]

**Additional information**

I created the QR code using this online generator: http://qrcode.kaywa.com/

All I did was point the QR Code directly to the file name so that it would use the phones built in functionality.

Comment: Surely that is a function of the iPhone, and nothing to do with the QR code?

Comment: You're going to need to give us a little more to go on here. How, exactly, do you scan the QR code and present the video as a result? What's the code in your application you use for this?

Comment: I have updated with some more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most QR code readers have a built in browser which they use to display web pages, and in this case presumambly, videos.  The problem is most likely with this built in browser.

Depending on the reader, it will probably have an option to open the URL in Safari instead.  I would bet that if you did so, the video would have sound.

Which reader are you using?  Incidentally, it works fine with [Optiscan](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/optiscan-qr-code-scanner-generator/id304099767?mt=8).

Comment: Thank you, I cannot remember the reader, it was one on my colleagues iPhone. However I think I have enough information to get back to them now.